# How to use dispatch from inside a client class?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

Continuing my adventure on creating a client / wrapper around axios with Zod and Redux, so that the client could handle errors during fetch and dispatch required state updates to Redux.

So far I have managed to implement Zod and the validation part into the client. Now I would like to somehow store possible error states or success states to redux. The problem is that no matter how I try to include `dispatch` into the class it doesn't seem to do anything.

Currently my wrapper client is this (no redux in this sample)

```js
interface RequestConfig<T extends z.ZodTypeAny> extends AxiosRequestConfig {
  responseSchema: T;
}

export class ValidatedAxiosClient {
  delete = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('DELETE');
  get = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('GET');
  patch = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('PATCH');
  put = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('PUT');
  post = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('POST');

  private unableToFetch = 'error:unableToFetch';

  constructor(private service: string, private baseUrl: string) {}

  private handleNetworkError<T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(
    error: HttpError,
    url: string,
    config: RequestConfig<T>
  ) {
    /**
     * Handle error...
     */
  }

  private handleZodError<T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(
    error: z.ZodError,
    url: string,
    config: RequestConfig<T>
  ) {
    /**
     * Parse and handle ZodError...
     */
  }

  private createValidatedAxiosRequest(method: HTTPMethod) {
    return async <T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(
      url: string,
      config: RequestConfig<T>
    ): Promise<z.infer<T>> => {
      try {

        const response = await axios({ ...config, method, url, baseURL: this.baseUrl });
        return config.responseSchema.parse(response);
      
      } catch (error: any) {

        if (error instanceof z.ZodError) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify({ error }, undefined, 4));
          this.handleZodError<T>(error, url, config);
        }

        if (error instanceof HttpError) {
          this.handleNetworkError<T>(error, url, config);
        }

      }
    };
  }
}
```

I am using `ThunkAction` from `redux-thunk` as following

```js
const WrappedClient = new ValidatedAxiosClient('UserService', 'http://localhost:3000')

export fetchUser =
  (userId: string): ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, Action<string>> =>
  async (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (getState().users.status === 'pending') return;

    dispatch(startedUsersLoading());

    const { name, age } = await WrappedClient.get('/user', {
      params: { userId },
      responseSchema: z.object({
        name: z.string(),
        age: z.number()
      })
    });

    dispatch(getUsersSuccess);
  }
```

Previously I was setting the loading and error states outside the client and in the `fetchUser` function. However, as I have several services and thus clients, that would be very repetitive and quite annoying to manage. I would like to move the state dispatch into the client itself. Is this even possible?

I tried to pass the dispatch into the `createValidatedAxiosRequest` in the client, but the dispatch was never called in there.

```js
  private createValidatedAxiosRequest(method: HTTPMethod) {
    return async <T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(
      url: string,
      dispatch: any,
      config: RequestConfig<T>
    ): Promise<z.infer<T>> => {
      try {

        dispatch(LoadingStateForThisService)
        
        const response = await axios({ ...config, method, url, baseURL: this.baseUrl });
        const parsedResponse = config.responseSchema.parse(response);
        
        dispatch(LoadingSuccess);

        return parsedResponse;
      
      } catch (error: any) {

        dispatch(someErrorStateSettingAction); // This is never called
        if (error instanceof z.ZodError) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify({ error }, undefined, 4));
          this.handleZodError<T>(error, url, config);
        }

        if (error instanceof HttpError) {
          this.handleNetworkError<T>(error, url, config);
        }

      }
    };
  }
```

I was wondering should I pass the dispatch to the constructor, but that got weird as well, because then I would need to create a new instance of the client every time a fetch function is called

```js
export fetchUser =
  (userId: string): ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, Action<string>> =>
  async (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (getState().users.status === 'pending') return;

    const WrappedClient = new ValidatedAxiosClient('UserService', dispatch, 'http://localhost:3000') // NOPE!! Don't want to instantiate this every time the function is called

    dispatch(startedUsersLoading());

    const { name, age } = await WrappedClient.get('/user', {
      params: { userId },
      responseSchema: z.object({
        name: z.string(),
        age: z.number()
      })
    });

    dispatch(getUsersSuccess);
  }
```

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do or should I try some different approach?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to pass and store an instance of the application's Redux store in this `ValidatedAxiosClient` class object instance. This would allow `ValidatedAxiosClient` to not only access any current state value when necessary, but to also dispatch actions to the store.

Example:

```js
import { store } from '../path/to/store';

type AppStore = typeof store;

export class ValidatedAxiosClient {
  delete = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('DELETE');
  get = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('GET');
  patch = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('PATCH');
  put = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('PUT');
  post = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('POST');

  private unableToFetch = 'error:unableToFetch';

  constructor(
    private service: string,
    private baseUrl: string,
    private store: AppStore, // <-- app store reference
  ) {}

  private handleNetworkError<T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(
    error: HttpError,
    url: string,
    config: RequestConfig<T>
  ) {
    /**
     * Handle error...
     */
  }

  private handleZodError<T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(
    error: z.ZodError,
    url: string,
    config: RequestConfig<T>
  ) {
    /**
     * Parse and handle ZodError...
     */
  }

  private createValidatedAxiosRequest(method: HTTPMethod) {
    return async <T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(
      url: string,
      config: RequestConfig<T>
    ): Promise<z.infer<T>> => {
      try {

        this.store.dispatch(LoadingStateForThisService());

        const response = await axios({
          ...config,
          method,
          url,
          baseURL: this.baseUrl
        });
        const parsedResponse = config.responseSchema.parse(response);
        
        this.store.dispatch(LoadingSuccess());

        return parsedResponse;
      } catch (error: any) {
        this.store.dispatch(someErrorStateSettingAction());

        if (error instanceof z.ZodError) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify({ error }, undefined, 4));
          this.handleZodError<T>(error, url, config);
        }

        if (error instanceof HttpError) {
          this.handleNetworkError<T>(error, url, config);
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

```js
import { store } from '../path/to/store';

const WrappedClient = new ValidatedAxiosClient(
  'UserService',
  'http://localhost:3000',
  store,
);
```

If you are looking for an alternative to this, or suggestions/recommendations, then I'd also highly recommend you check out [Redux-Toolkit Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview). Instead of defining a class with generic HTTP methods and micromanage all the loading/fetching states/statuses, you defined an API slice that defines the endpoints the app uses, and Redux-Toolkit *automagically* handles the loading/fetching status and generates the query hooks the app would use, and it's integrated into the Redux store the app uses.

Comment: I had to check the proposed solution soon. I had looked at the RTK-Query before, but I am not sure, if it's possible to implement validation with Zod into it. I guess it might be possible, but how, that's yet again another question. I'll take another look at the RTK-Query for sure.